# magento 1 database migrations rollback

Tags: php, magento, migration

I am interested in studding magento migrations. 
I know how magento does migration from one module version to another. 
But I didn't find a "Rollback" function in each of migration files.
As I see all magento module "install" scripts are simple php scenarios with code:

```
/** @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

// do some stuff

$installer->endSetup();
```

Or event simpler:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($this->getTable('googlebase/types'), 'target_country', "varchar(2) not null default 'US'");
```

So, how magento knows what to do in case you need to change your version from 1.1.0 to 1.0.9, for example.
And how can I rollback to any version that I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollbacks are manual reversion to a pre-upgrade database version.

Always test the upgrade process on a development environment thoroughly to make sure that the upgrade will be successful, always back up the database before committing live and always have a standard set of tests to run after you do the upgrade.

Standard procedure for an upgrade is to duplicate your live database and upgrade on the duplicate.